# Upgraded CPU, PC switched on but blank screen

Tags: boot

Decided I wanted to improve my processing performance for Microsoft Flight Sim and to update to Windows 11... Old specs as follows...

Motherboard ... Asus Prime A320m-k
CPU ... Amd Ryzen 5 2600 quad core
GPU ... GeForce 1600
2x ssd HDD with approx 1.5 Tb
16 gb RAM

Upgraded to a Ryzen 5 4600 six core and upgraded from the stock fan to a Cooler Master fan

CPU Seated fine, thermopaste applied, fan seated no issues.
Turned on and everything powers up but no display at all (says no signal detected)
Also noticed my drive light not coming on now but figured I woul dhave to go into the BIOS settings on a first time boot so that bit didnt concern me too much.

Checked all cables and connections and tried again... same result.

Removed new CPU and re-installed the 2600 and again, same result.

As I cannot get a display, I cannot go into the BIOS settings as pressing Delete or F2 does nothing at all.

Have I killed it or can someone help?

Comment: I presume you have upgraded the firmware to at least 5862?  If you are getting the same results AFTER you put the original CPU back into the socket, that indicates a hardware problem. Of course you should absolutely NOT be using 5862 considering the current version of the firmware is 6061.

Comment: How would you advise I troubleshoot the hardware issue? Where to start?

Comment: If you don't happen to know what the firmware was, before you started the upgrade, I would start from scratch. Verify every single connection is properly connected. I would even try a different display and different cable to that display. If it still fails to boot, assume the socket on the motherboard is the problem, and go from there.

Comment: also note, that some firmware settings may have been changed after the swap. since your new chip supports integrated graphics and you use a standalone GPU, you may want to try the other monitor port, to see if your system defaulted to using the other video device.

Comment: `Removed new CPU and re-installed the 2600 and again, same result` so now the original CPU doesn't work? chances are you have *broken* something - have you tried clearing CMOS